# AH00124 Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error

Tags: php, .htaccess

Hi my colleague has several sites hosted on Apache 2.4.46 with PHP 5.6.40 and using cPanel 86.0 (build 27). A few months back, accessing one of the sites stopped working (e.g. http://test.example). It would just show a blank page (500 Internal Server Error) after redirecting to a login page (http://test.example/login.php).

The server log would should many of these entries:

*AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.*

This seems to be an error caused by the htaccess file. Have found several articles on this but our htaccess code (below) is different compared to the ones found, and am having trouble interpreting them. Could someone advise if any of these lines could potentially cause this issue? TIA

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.example$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.test\.example$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/test\.example\/login\.php" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: That rule only does a redirect from the root path to login.php, so it should not affect that second request for the login.php at all. Maybe that script itself issues a location header (to itself maybe?), when something goes wrong with checking login status?

Comment: @04FS thanks for the reply. Will try to get hold of the login script.